# How to automate firebase deploy in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm looking for a solution for "Automate" my firebase deploy. I want to deploy my local code Zip file to firebase on a single click.

Comment: Zip file? Isn't your final build of react project is into the output folder something like `/build`? Or using other than CRA?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shell script to execute the firebase deployment and run it. You can also create a Task in VS Code and execute the shell script as part of the Task.

Answer (score 0):

this command will generate token for you and after this process your whole deployment process is automatic

```
firebase login:ci
```

after generating token you need to deploy token with

```
firebase deploy --token
```

suggestion: [how to deploy react firebase project automatically](https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-continuous-deployment-with-react-firebase-and-github-actions/)